# Fabric installer page on Safari for iPadOS 13.1 is not recognized as a "device"

Tags: safari, google-fabric, ipados

I recently updated to iPadOS 13.1 and I can't get "Beta by Crashlytics" to accept an iPad Pro 12" as a device that can install the required software from `https://apps.crashlytics.com/register/...`

I am met by a screen that says

```
                                Beta by Crashlytics

Open the invitation email on your device to begin registering for beta testing
```

Can I do anything to make Safari on iPadOS 13.1 accept my invitation, or do I have to wait for a bugfix for this?

Thanks.

## Alternate answer

Thanks to iCediCe for showing me in the right direction. Following their advice made me realize there is an even easier way.

The easier way - instead of making all webpages conform to mobile - you can make a specific webpage conform to mobile.

Press `aA` on the leftmost point of the address bar in Safari, a menu pops up and there you can select "Request Mobile Website". After that Crashlytics/Beta will show up.

Comment: Great tip with the aA button! Never knew you could do that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Goto  Settings -> Safari -> Request Desktop Website -> All websites and disable it. This will cause it to use iOS user agent string not macOS user agent string thous making it work again.